# Не работает Mysql запрос

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть запрос фильтрации товаров:

```
SELECT 
    `t1`.`title`, 
     count(*) as cnt, 
    `t2`.`price` 
FROM `t1` INNER JOIN `t2` ON `t1`.`collection_id` = `t2`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `t3` ON `t1`.`id` = `t3`.`product_id` 
INNER JOIN `t4` ON `t1`.`id` = `t4`.`product_id` 
WHERE 
    `t1`.`section_id` = 3 AND 
    ((`t3`.`value` IN ('Бытовой') AND `t1`.`brand_id` IN (18) AND 
    `t4`.`name` IN (2.5)) OR (`t3`.`value` IN ('Полукоммерческий') AND 
    `t1`.`brand_id` IN (18) AND `t4`.`name` IN (2.5))) 
GROUP BY 
    `t1`.`id` 
HAVING 
    cnt = 1 
ORDER BY 
    `t2`.`price`
LIMIT 30
```

где `t1` - таблица товаров, `t2` - таблица коллекций товаров с ценами, `t3` - таблица характеристик к каждому товару (id | product_id | title | value), `t4` - таблица с размерами товара.

Проблема в том, что в phpmyadmin он прекрасно выполняется, а через движок не работает. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: покажите, как вы его в php выполняете? и не забудьте приложить текст ошибки.

Comment: `if (!$result) {
    die('Неверный запрос: ' . mysql_error());
}`

Comment: А вы создайте отдельный скрипт, который будет подключатся к указанной базе данных и делать запрос. В скрипте включите отображение ошибок.

Comment: @webstackoverload , сделал, как вы и сказали, все без ошибок. Причем, результат не проходит, например, когда к бренду добавляешь какой-то фильтр.

Comment: *а через движок не работает* Запрос в принципе не может "не работать". Он либо выполняется и возвращает набор данных (возможно, пустой), либо приводит к ошибке выполнения. Из Вашего вопроса непонятно, с каким случаем мы имеем дело.

Comment: Все верно сказали выше. Попробуйте сделать простейший SELECT запрос по конкретному полю или айди из скрипта.